# VS2010 Changing style sheet based on the browser

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, is there a way of changing the Cascading Style sheet on the server-side based on the client browser? I want to create different style sheets for the different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera, Safari etc..) and specify which one to use from the master page.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with KP; use a single stylesheet. 
If you are using modernizr [sic], then you can style for different browsers very simply, for example:

```
someContainer {
   /* standards based CSS */
}

someContainer.ie6 {
   /* special CSS for IE6 */ 
}
```

My suggestion is to use the new HTML5 Boilerplate which includes modernizr. You'll be glad you did!

Check out the links below and don't look back. :)

[Link to Boilerplate for HTML5](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

[Link to Modernizr - ease the chaos!](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good article on detecting browser type in asp.net:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx

Once you detect the browser type using for example, a switch statement on `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type`, you can easily insert a css reference into the page, with code such as:

```
HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();
cssLink.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
cssLink.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";

switch(HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Type)
{
    Case "Firefox":
        //use a certain path depending on browser type
        cssLink.Attributes["href"] = "firefox.css"; 
        break;
    Case "Internet Explorer"
        cssLink.Attributes["href"] = "IE.css";
        break;

    //and so on

}

Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);
```

I don't know what the actual string values of `Browser.Type` will be for each browser. You'd have to test.

Even with the above, I'd still recommend using a single stylesheet for all browsers. With a little effort you can make a page render almost identically across all major browsers.

First I'd recommend starting with a reset CSS file such as the [YUI 2 Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) or [YUI 3 Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/). From there most styles will apply well and consistently across browsers. With all default styles reset you can build out your styles with complete control.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if I follow fully but you can specify these in the App_browsers folder of your project.